# reading values from windows registry?

Tags: vb6, registry, registrykey

I'm working on a program that will be installed on multiple computers on a factory floor. this program has a log in screen and one of the requirements is that it should automatically input the machine name depending on the computer. so i have decided that putting a key in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE with the machine name would be a good idea so that the employee cannot mess with it. the only problem is that i am clueless as to how to read a key from the registry.

i have found code that seems to be creating a key and reading/writing to it but i just need to read it im not going to make one or write to one. this is the code,

```
Dim strString As String
Dim cdReg As New registryfncs
cdReg.CreateKey ("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Expert Resource Management")

strString = cdReg.SetStringValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Expert Resource Management", "Owner", Date)
strString = cdReg.GetStringValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Expert Resource Management", "Owner")
```

i would like to know if this is the right way to go or if im hopelessly lost.

Comment: There's plenty of solutions here:  https://www.google.com/search?q=vb6+read+key+from+registry&oq=vb6+read+key+from+registry.  What exactly is the problem?  Did you test the code?

Comment: i did input the code and i put in the values i needed but it turns out  `registryfncs` is not a native vb6 declare object. im not sure where it comes from. im going through a buch on articles from google searches on reading registry keys in vb6 but none are really helping me, im not sure what to use and what not to use.

Answer (score 2):

An easy way to get the name of the local machine, is:

```
Dim UserDomain As String
UserDomain = Environ("USERDOMAIN")
```

This would require NT or later, but I assume that is not an issue in spite of it being VB6.

If you also want the user name:

```
Dim UserName As String
UserName = Environ("USERNAME")
```

Should be easier than the registry.  There is also an API approach, but this should work.

It is also available from `HCU\Volatile Environment\UserDomain` and UserName, but given the subkey name, I'd stay with the `Environ` approach (which could read a CUSTOM name if you wanted).

---

For completeness, the .NET version without using the VB namespace would be:

```
Dim UserDomain As String = 
     = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERDOMAIN")
```

Answer (score 2):

i figured it out, i needed to read a key that i made in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE called Test Machine that i could input any string i needed. here is the code,

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
Test

End Sub

Private Function Registry_Read(Key_Path, Key_Name) As Variant

On Error Resume Next

Dim Registry As Object
Set Registry = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Registry_Read = Registry.RegRead(Key_Path & Key_Name)
End Function

Private Sub Test()

txtMachine.Text = Registry_Read("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\", "Test Machine")
End Sub
```

i inputted the value into a text box on the form, which is read only.